# Oracle security procedure

Tags: database, oracle, security

In Oracle, 
- I want to ensure that owner of trigger must match table owner. 
- Also the views should be restricted. The user must not be able to query system views and tables.

Comment: What are you afraid will happen, what are you trying to avoid? This sounds like one of those *bizarre, uninformed manager direction to an unequipped employee" type thing.

Answer (score 3):

Generally only the owner of a table will have privileges to create triggers on it. DBAs may have the privilege CREATE ANY TRIGGER, but protecting a database from a DBA is whole different order of question.

There are a number of system views (eg USER_TABLES, ALL_USERS) which you can't revoke access on, but they will only reveal what the user has been granted access to. Again the DBA will have access to views prefixed DBA_ and 'views' prefixed V$ (which are a bit odd in that they show operational information about the database and not data that is stored on disk anywhere) and tables owned by SYS.

Comment: Hello. In  the triggers what i want is there should be a check that when a trigger is fired there has to be a check that the (if(trigger.owner==table.owner, then fire else permission_denied)

Comment: Not practical. Anyone who can create triggers on someone else's table would almost certainly have the authority to disable any such check.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly is it that you want to accomplish?
Normally, we create roles that give access to only the application tables and views. 
The owner of the application grants privileges to those roles and 
the roles are granted to your users.
As long as the owner of the tables only has the regular 'create xxx' privileges, there is not much to worry for. Normally we need access to some system tables and views.

What data do you want to hide? Most of the views don't reveal more than already is known by the application.

Don't give 'xxxx ANY' privileges to anyone. Most of the time when those privs are requested it is because of laziness. They are rarely needed.

Ronald.

Comment: "Don't give 'xxxx ANY' privileges to anyone" At least almost never.